# Browser isn't reading gzipped file - MEAN app

Tags: angularjs, express, mean, gzip

I have a gulpfile that gzips my js:

```
gulp.task('angular', function() {
  return gulp.src(['public/app/*.js'])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gzip({ append: true}))            // Relevant line here
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/app/dist'));
});
```

In my index.html file:

```
  <script src="app/dist/app.js.gz"></script>
```

When I comment out the line that does the gzipping, I don't have a problem. With it included, however, Angular outputs a message in the Chrome console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

The gzipped file has characters that appear to be diamonds, so maybe it wasn't gzipped properly and the browser isn't reading the characters.

Also one other issue, is that you can use compress with express 4.0. I have added it into my server file:

```
var compress = require('compression');

...

app.use(compress());                       // Relevant line here
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '1mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization');
    next();
});
```

I don't know if this is in the correct spot and if this is the line of code that allows the browser to read .gz files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to gzip both in gulp and in Express -

```
app.use(compress());
```

would suffice for your static assets.

(Doesn't explain your exact error but sounds as if the browser is receiving a double gzipped file, and hence compressed output that it cannot read)

Comment: Went ahead and removed the lines from gulp and made necessary adjustments in html and it appears to work now. Did a Google page speed insights tests and it says the site is all compressed.

Comment: Also if you can accept this answer would be appreciated